# findByAnd incompatible types

Tags: java, ofbiz

I'm trying to use method [findByAnd](https://ci.apache.org/projects/ofbiz/site/javadocs/org/ofbiz/entity/Delegator.html#find-java.lang.String-org.ofbiz.entity.condition.EntityCondition-org.ofbiz.entity.condition.EntityCondition-java.util.Set-java.util.List-org.ofbiz.entity.util.EntityFindOptions-).

This is part of my code:

```
ArrayList<String> orderBy;
orderBy.add("productId");

GenericDelegator delegator = (GenericDelegator) DelegatorFactory.getDelegator("default");
GenericValue product = null;

try {
    product = delegator.findByAnd("Product", UtilMisc.toMap("productName", productName), orderBy, false);
} catch (GenericEntityException e) {
    return Response.serverError().entity(e.toString()).build();
}
```

In this line

```
product = delegator.findByAnd("Product", UtilMisc.toMap("productName", productName), orderBy, false);
```

I get this error:

[image]

How to correct it? I don't understand how types can be incompatible in my code.

Comment: You don't understand how `List<GenericValue>` is not a `GenericValue`?

Comment: @Kayaman no, since I'm passing orderBy as an argument which is an ArrayList<String>

Comment: Maybe you should concentrate on what's coming out, not what's going in.

Comment: @Kayaman do you have a solution?

Comment: What does `findByAnd` return?

Comment: List of GenericValue

Comment: And what is `product`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125611/discussion-between-daniela-maia-and-kayaman).

Comment: Good luck. I'm sure you'll be surprised at how simple your mistake was when you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the findByAnd method returns a List of GenericValue objects, each GenericValue represents a row in the Product table.
The following code will work:

```
List<GenericValue> products = delegator.findByAnd("Product", UtilMisc.toMap("productName", productName), orderBy, false);
```